# Django devuelve error 400 al hacer petición POST en una API rest

Tags: python, django, api, djangorestframework

Hola estoy lidiando con este problema al cual no le encuentro solución, cuando hago la petición POST a mi api rest desde thunder client o cualquier otro método recibo un error 400 Bad Request, al parecer la API no toma los valores enviados. A continuación les dejo mi codigo para ver si alguien puede encontrar el error.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from .serializers import UserSerializer, SignUpSerializer


def get_auth_for_user(user):
   tokens = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    return {
       'user': UserSerializer(user).data,
       'tokens': {
           'access': str(tokens.access_token),
           'refresh': str(tokens),
       }
   }


class SignInView(APIView):
   permission_classes = [AllowAny]

   def post(self, request):
       username = request.data.get('username')
       password = request.data.get('password')
    
       if not username or password:
           return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
       user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        
       if not user:
           return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        
       user_data = get_auth_for_user(user)

       return Response(user_data)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'name',
            'rank'
        ]

    def get_name(self, obj):
        fname = obj.first_name.capitalize()
        lname = obj.last_name.capitalize()
        return fname + ' ' + lname
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Así es como estoy enviando la petición:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También dejo el error que muestra la consola de Django por si sirve de ayuda:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente haciendo uso de django-cors-headers pero no soluciono nada, dejo a continuación como lo implemente en settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'corsheaders',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework_simplejwt',
'users'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('http://localhost:8000', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',)
```

Comment: Estoy casi 100% segura de que `if not username or password:` está mal escrito. Básicamente está diciendo "si no hay username o hay contraseña:"... La condición no hace lo que creés que hace.